# Is this proper way to pass parameters?

Tags: c#, syntax

Reading [this](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) article I found one strange way to pass parameters to object:

```
_saveProductCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => SaveProduct(),
                param => (CurrentProduct != null)
```

Is this typo or proper way to pass parameters?

Comment: it is relay command it is passed this way

Comment: It is if the parameters are delegates or expressions which means you can pass lambdas.

Comment: See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Are you asking about how both lambdas don't use the `param` input?

Comment: @juharr: why it couldn't have been `() => SaveProduct()`. Is `param` just dummy variable?

Comment: `()` means that the `Action` doesn't receive any parameters, but `RelayCommand` requires an Action with one parameter (`Action<object>`), so even when you do not use it you have to declare it.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, it is a dummy variable.  and `() => SaveProduct()` wouldn't work because that represents a delegate that takes no input, but the `RelayCommand` wants an `Action<object>` (basically a void delegate that has an `object` as an input). However some people might use `_ => SaveProduct()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is not something that applies to general properties, for example if the parameter was a string you would not be able to use the `name => statement` syntax.

If you look at the definition of RelayCommand you will see that the parameters are of type `Action` this is a special type that allows you to pass blocks of code or methods as objects, these are generally called Delegates.

The syntax you are referring to is called a `Lambda` and they come in a few forms.

The simplest is `() => doSomething()` in this case the lambda does not take any parameters and only calls the `doSomething` method.

The next is a lambda that takes a parameter `param => doSomething(param)` in this code the variable `param` is just a local variable for the code body of the lambda to be able to use, and the code that executes the lambda will need to pass something in, here is a more complete example;

```
var myLambda = param => doSomething(param);
myLambda("some string value");
```

So in this example the string will be passed to the `doSomething` method.

These examples have only covered lambdas that will convert down to the `Action` class, but you can also write a lambda that will give you a `Func`. There is also another form called `Predicate` this is essentially an Action that returns true or false;

I would suggest doing some additional reading on the [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) class the [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) class and the [Predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) class.